# SUMIF function with criteria in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

Say I have to sum up the cells in column B if their corresponding cells in column A <= the value in some specific cell in column C. Instead of `SUMIF(A1:A10,"<=10",B1:B10)`, I tried `SUMIF(A1:A10,"<=C1",B1:B10)` and it didn't work.

How do you fix it so that the criteria of the `SUMIF` function involves the value in a specific cell? I'd like to set it this way because I have to apply the `SUMIF` function to the entire column. Ideally, the formulae in the cells of column D will be something similar to

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"<=C1",B1:B10)


=SUMIF(A1:A10,"<=C2",B1:B10)
```

etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,">="&C1,$B$1:$B$10)
```

Put it in **D1** and fill down.